# Unit Test Custom Validator in Spring Validation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, validation

I have a custom validator as below

```
@Component
public class RequestValidator implements Validator {

    private SmartValidator smartValidator;

    @Autowired
    public RequestValidator(@Qualifier("smartValidator") SmartValidator smartValidator){
        this.smartValidator = smartValidator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return RequestWrapper.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
        RequestWrapper requestWrapper = (RequestWrapper) object;
        if(requestWrapper.getRequest() instanceof UserRequest) {
        UserRequest userRequest = (UserRequest) requestWrapper.getRequest();
        smartValidator.validate(userRequest, errors);
    }
}
```

The bean for validation is as below

```
    public class UserRequest{

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
        @Pattern(regexp = ValidationRegex.ALPHA_SPECIAL)
        private String firstName;

        @Size(max = 1)
        @Pattern(regexp = ValidationRegex.ALPHA)
        private String middleInitial;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
        @Pattern(regexp = ValidationRegex.ALPHA_SPECIAL)
        private String lastName;

        //more fields and getters and setters
}
```

My test class looks like this

```
public class UserRequestValidatorTest {

    @Mock
    SmartValidator smartValidator;

    @InjectMocks
    UserRequestValidator userRequestValidator;

    private UserRequest userRequest;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        userRequest = new UserRequest();

        userRequest.setFirstName("FirstName");
        userRequest.setMiddleInitial("M");
        userRequest.setLastName("LastName");
   }

    @Test
    public void validateUserRequest_testFirstName() throws Exception {

        userRequest.setFirstName(null);
        RequestWrapper requestWrapper = new RequestWrapper();
        requestWrapper.setRequest(userRequest);

        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(requestWrapper, "requestWrapper");
        userRequestValidator.validate(requestWrapper, errors);

        assertTrue(errors.hasErrors());
        assertNotNull(errors.getFieldError("firstName"));
    }
  //More tests
```

}

When I run the test i get the below exception.

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:92)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
    at com.user.validator.UserRequestValidatorTest.validateUpdateUserRequest_testFirstName(UserRequestValidatorTest.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I am providing values so that the first name validation throws null error.
Cannot understand what I am writing incorrect which is not able to validate the fields.

The exception that is mentioned is occurring at `assertTrue(errors.hasErrors())`
Even the next line `assertNotNull(errors.getFieldError("firstName"))` is also failing with the same error.

Can someone review and help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: what is going on in the BeanPropertyBindingResult contrcutor?

Comment: Didn't get what you meant. I am passing the object that I am passing to the validator. What is not right about it?

Comment: Im not questioning what is right or wrong. You are asserting based on the internal structure of the Errors class and that is not posted. Also those assertions does not seem to be much relevant with what the method under test is doing. I would simply verify that smartValidator.validate method is called.. nothing more to test there

Comment: Calling smartValidator.validate was an option but apart from that I also have a few custom validation code that executes after that. So I need to keep the code in that fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok So, First I made a blasphemous mistake of making the SmartValidator as @mock.
This means that my validations were actually not executed. This was really foolish.
Second, even when I removed the @mock from Smartvalidator it still didn't work. Coz I needed to inject the instance of SmartValidator in to my validation class UserRequestValidator.
Hence I used the below annotations on the test class.
Also I marked the validator in the test class as Autowired.
That solved it.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class UserRequestValidatorTest{
    @Autowired
    UserRequestValidator userRequestValidator;

    //Remaining things same as in question

}
```

Comment: I'm glad you recognized this.  Mocking the thing you're meant to test is a common mistake when mocking.